# How to load a XML file in a database in Java?

Tags: java, sql, xml

I found anything about an API in Java to load or convert XML to SQL.

Do you know a solution for this?

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myExport version="1.0" myExportVersion="8.5">
  <elements>
    <element name="car">
      <columns>
        <column name="brand" category="identity" />
        <column name="commentary" category="other" />
      </columns>
      <datas>
        <data number="1">
          <column name="brand">bmw</column>
          <column name="commentary">I like this car</column>
        </data> 
        </datas>
    </element>
    <element name="tchat">
      <columns>
        <column name="thread" category="identity" />
        <column name="message" category="other" />
      </columns>
      <datas>
        <data number="1">
          <column name="thread">1</column>
          <column name="message">Hello</column>
        </data>
         <data number="2">
          <column name="thread">1</column>
          <column name="message">Hello, how are you ?</column>
        </data>
        </datas>
    </element>
  </elements>
</myExport>
```

Explanations:

- "Columns" explain how the data are structured (like SQL Table).
- "Datas" are the data (like row in SQL)
- The structure is random, I don't know the names.

Comment: I don't think there are apis to do that. This is a two step process: first you parse the xml file into Java objects and then you save the objects to the database.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, I will create an object Table with attributes name and columns. I will map "car" to name, brand and commentary to columns. But how to convert this object into my database ? The first answer is, yeah use entities, I thought to Jpa but it's not possible to use dynamic name table and columns, right ?? My solution will be to transform this object into SQL language. I will produce "CREATE TABLE car"... from my object Table.
That's why I asking if you known an API can do that or load directly XML in embedded database. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you for help

Comment: I thank to XSLT, but I don't know if that can do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob data type for storing xml in Database. if you are using jpa you can refer to below example
https://donovanmuller.blog/storing-xml-natively-in-oracle-with-jpa/

Comment: That's not what they're asking.